# Can i get the Lines of code in a Azure Analytics view?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, powerbi, lines-of-code

I'd like to create a dashboard in PowerBI including the lines of code of the Azure DevOps project. It would be nice to see how that grows by the day.

I googled this question but could not find anything related to this, unfortunately. Also in the create custom views i could not find anything that did the trick. I'm not even sure its possible, but i would love to get it working.

I'd like to know if its possible at first, and at second i'd love to know how i can get it to work!

Thanks as allways,

Greeting.

Answer (score 0):

There is description here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-analytics

> With Analytics, you can get engaging insights on your work items and
>   automated tests. We are actively working to add more data from other
>   services, such as Repos, Pipelines, Manual Test, and Artifacts.

We have to wait new updates to get reports from source code repos.

Comment: I keep thinking about it, but would it be possible to request it out of the API? and then load it into PowerBI? In that case, that would be fine too.